Support with recoding likert questions in R
I am new to R but i need to use it as i cannot access spss at this moment. So my issue is i am trying to recode my likert scale questions i already took out the array i want and renamed to "lik". I have also changed the column names to "life satisfaction Q1-Q4".
I am trying to recode the likert questions and have done thes
rmydata.reloaded1 <- lik %>%
  mutate(across(c("Life Satisfaction Q1", "Life Satisfaction Q2", "Life Satisfaction Q3", "Life Satisfaction Q4"),
                ~ recode(., "Disagree" = 1, "Neutral" = 2, "Agree" = 3, "Strongly agree" = 4)))

I recieved a error warning
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `Life Satisfaction Q1 = recode(...)`.
Caused by error in `recode()`:
! unused arguments (Disagree = 1, Neutral = 2, Agree = 3, `Strongly agree` = 4)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
`funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.

I also  did this
mydata.reloaded1 <- lik %>% mutate_at(c("Life Satisfaction Q1", "Life Satisfaction Q2", "Life Satisfaction Q3", "Life Satisfaction Q4"), 
+                                       funs(recode(., "Disagree"=1, "Neutral"=2, "Agree"=3, "Strongly agree"=4)))

and recieved this
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `Life Satisfaction Q1 = recode(...)`.
Caused by error in `recode()`:
! unused arguments (Disagree = 1, Neutral = 2, Agree = 3, `Strongly agree` = 4)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
`funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.

Hence, i can not seem to figure what i keep doing wrong, any support would be appreciated.

Welcome to SO! Your first example is actually valid, even though recode() is superseded in favor of case_match() . At least in R 4.4  and with up to date Tidyverse packages. Could you please edit your question and change your code to be a minimal reproducible example? I.e something that you (and others) could copy-paste to a clean R environment and end up with that same error,  in addition to pieces of code that throw errors, please  include all loaded libraries and a small sample form your dataset, output from dput(head(lik))  would be ideal.  sessionInfo() ouput would also help.

You want to use the splice operator here (!!!):
rmydata.reloaded1 <- lik %>%
    mutate(across(
        c("Life Satisfaction Q1", "Life Satisfaction Q2", "Life Satisfaction Q3", "Life Satisfaction Q4"),
        ~ recode(., !!!c(
            "Disagree" = 1,
            "Neutral" = 2,
            "Agree" = 3,
            "Strongly agree" = 4
        ))
    ))

You may also look into looking for dplyr::case_when or dplyr::case_match.
The syntax is a little different.
rmydata.reloaded1 <- lik %>%
    mutate(across(
        c(
            "Life Satisfaction Q1",
            "Life Satisfaction Q2",
            "Life Satisfaction Q3",
            "Life Satisfaction Q4"
        ),
        ~ case_match(., "Disagree" ~ 1, "Neutral" ~ 2, "Agree" ~ 3, "Strongly agree" ~ 4)
    ))

rmydata.reloaded1
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  `Life Satisfaction Q1` `Life Satisfaction Q2` `Life Satisfaction Q3` `Life Satisfaction Q4`
                   <dbl>                  <dbl>                  <dbl>                  <dbl>
1                      1                      1                      1                      1
2                      2                      2                      2                      2
3                      3                      3                      3                      3
4                      4                      4                      4                      4

data
lik <- tibble(
    `Life Satisfaction Q1` = c("Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly agree"),
    `Life Satisfaction Q2` = c("Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly agree"),
    `Life Satisfaction Q3` = c("Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly agree"),
    `Life Satisfaction Q4` = c("Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly agree"))

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  `Life Satisfaction Q1` `Life Satisfaction Q2` `Life Satisfaction Q3` `Life Satisfaction Q4`
  <chr>                  <chr>                  <chr>                  <chr>                 
1 Disagree               Disagree               Disagree               Disagree              
2 Neutral                Neutral                Neutral                Neutral               
3 Agree                  Agree                  Agree                  Agree                 
4 Strongly agree         Strongly agree         Strongly agree         Strongly agree 

